# Can't get startx to work 'Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console'

Tags: virtual-console

this is what I get when I try to:

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-76:~$ startx
xauth:  file /home/ubuntu/.Xauthority does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-89-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ip-172-31-25-76 4.4.0-1022-aws #31-Ubuntu SMP Tu                                                                                                             e Jun 27 11:27:55 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1022-aws root=UUID=3e13556e-                                                                                                             d28d-407b-bcc6-97160eafebe1 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0
Build Date: 09 August 2017  09:38:57PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubu                                                                                                             ntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sat Oct  7 21:22:37 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down error setting MTRR (base = 0xf0000000, size =                                                                                                              0x00400000, type = 1) Invalid argument (22)
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```